# Responsive file manager display unknown error when uploading file

Tags: php

Whenever i'm uploading a file, it displays unknown error. but if i check the server directory, the file is uploaded but no thumbnail file created. this occur on live hosting while in localhost everyting works well.

Can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: what is the error you get, more infomration is needed. For example the file may have the wrong or unsupported encoding, or many other reasons. So it is uploaded but cannnot be processed as image

Comment: Have you checked your .htaccess and php.ini settings?

Comment: I used the same .htaccess with the same site on another domain where everything works well. And i checked the php.ini i don't realy see what can cause it. memory_limit, upload_max_filesize and those related configuration are 128mb so what else! If i upload the same image with a my script outside file manager it uplods successfully. also i set the thumbs folder permission from 755 to 777 still...